# How do I authenticate with HashiCorp Cloud vault using the AWS IAM auth method?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I've configured a HashiCorp Vault cluster in their cloud and done the necessary steps mentioned at - https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/cloud/vault-auth-method-aws?in=vault/cloud-ops . I've created the required AWS roles , users & policies and am able to connect to the vault using the admin token via the CLI.

However for our Java application I'm trying to have our spring boot application authenticate using the AWS iam auth method. I've got the bootstrap.yml to have the following :

```
spring.cloud.vault:
  uri: {HashiCorp Cloud Public URL}
  authentication: AWS_IAM
  kv:
    enabled:true
  aws-iam:
    role: vault-role-for-aws-ec2role
    aws-path: aws
    endpoint-uri: sts.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

The role "vault-role-for-aws-ec2role" is configured to use the policy to read the key values :

### Grant 'read' permission to paths prefixed by 'kv/test/ec2'

```
path "kv/test/ec2" {
  capabilities = [ "read" ]
}
```

However when I try to startup my springboot application it fails giving the following error :

2022-06-22 02:50:16.050  INFO 21435 --- [           main] o.s.v.c.e.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource  : Vault location [secret/application/dev] not resolvable: hostname cannot be null
2022-06-22 02:50:16.051  WARN 21435 --- [           main] LeaseEventPublisher$LoggingErrorListener : [RequestedSecret [path='secret/application', mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] hostname cannot be null

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname cannot be null

I'm not sure what could be going wrong. Can anyone help ?